# How do I register my iOS app to open certain file types?

Tags: ios, info-plist

I'm struggling on this issue, sending and receiving data by email from my ios application.
It send alright, but when I have to open ( hold tap on the file) suppose to prompt me if i want to open with my application. I set the file extension on ipz.
Here is a copy of my info-plist.

Do I miss something?

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>English</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleDocument</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypename</key>
        <string>iPrick List Document</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.ipricklist.iPrickList.ipz</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>logo1</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>iPrick List Document</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.ipricklist.iPrickList</string>
        </array>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.ipricklist.iPrickList.ipz</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>logo1.png</string>
    <string>Default@2x.png</string>
    <string>Default.png</string>
    <string>logo2.png</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>logo1.png</string>
            <string>Default@2x.png</string>
            <string>Default.png</string>
            <string>logo2.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.ipricklist.iPrickList</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSMainNibFile</key>
<string>MainWindow</string>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
<true/>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>iPrick List Document</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.ipricklist.iPrickList.ipz</string>
        <key>UTTypeSize320IconFile</key>
        <string>logo1</string>
        <key>UTTypeSize64IconFile</key>
        <string>logo2</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecifications</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>ipz</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/iPrickList</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)